# Interval count from set

Tags: combinatorics

I came across a counting question which I couldn't understand.

The set $\{1, 2, 3\}$ contains 6 nonempty intervals: $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$, $\{3\}$, $\{1, 2\}$, $\{2, 3\}$ and $\{1, 2, 3\}$. How many nonempty intervals does $\{1, 2, ...,10\}$ contain?

What I don't get how the example set $\{1, 2, 3\}$ translate to interval? Why is $\{1,3\}$ missing from the intervals listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a set of consecutive integers, the discrete interval from integer $a$ to integer $a+n$ is

$$\{a,a+1,...,a+n\},$$

so $\{1,3\}$ is not a valid interval in your example since it has a gap (it is missing $2$).

For a set of $n$ integers, the number of nonempty intervals is

$$1+2+...+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$